# ReactJs - TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-state-management

I have an array of objects:

```
var subcategories = [{name:'gloves', tag:'wool'}, {name:'boots', tag: 'leather'}]
```

All I want to do is to find the index of the object to change a name or a tag. I use this function:

```
function setSubcat(val, index, lang){
   var newArr = []
   var obj = {
      'name': val
   }
   subcategories.map((val, i)=>{
      if(index === i){
         var newObj = Object.assign(val, obj)
         newArr.push(newObj)
      }
      newArr.push(val)
   })
   setSubcategories(newArr)
}
```

The error happens at `var newObj = Object.assign(val, obj)`

I thought the error means I can't mutate the state directly and so I have to make a copy. I thought that mapping through `subcategories` and push it into a local `newArr` means I made a copy of the array. But it wasn't working when I wanted to change a value of object in it so I used Object.assign which I thought would deep copy the particular object from the array, but it's not working either.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Not reproducible: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwOYYgEwJKQC2yA3gFDKXIhyEQBcyAzmFKBgDQVViaMtsQGMgF8yANzhRmAVwBGCOJAwB7NhCbIAvMgDaJGnXoByDABsV4jcY7JeGEwHcVKs8ZG2DtBsbkuwTDZ2fMjGZhBKABbQ7gC6ANxkZDAyIAhgwCogzBBgAMryimAAFJJm-KzstqA4EAAejCAyhHLQtgD6ZnBCjN0AngCU5FSS0iAQjgCCUFCM6Fi4BBCEurHaerHcyKPIKnIAVowAClIZcGYAPPPY+EQAfOvDVJTGhhDGjGVbYlRMhUoQVTqJgAOkIcAADsVSudqgMtHcns9gDBijV6totDpgEMts9KDtxo4APIHdak-YQdIguBMJjADAgGFmWx7fYDPH4onTKAgiEyJiRYpEikc-HIETICBmJgoJFUbkzPkCoVlMX4n6UETq5AILJMVwQEEWDDCiY8gaJKgAemtsvy-2UamAGjNUxmHLEZHtBQUSmKrwmADlvEEAAy2VK1GCgXCWoA

Comment: agreed; could you post more code or a playground example?  this code is fine as is.

Comment: Please don't use `map` that way. Everyone is going to read that code and think "Is that a bug? I need to ask him....". `map` is for transforming each element, `forEach` is for visiting each element.

Comment: Still working with `map` used correctly: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwOYYgEwJKQC2yA3gFDKXIhyEQBcyAzmFKBgDQVViaMtsQGMgF8yANzhRmAVwBGCOJAwB7NhCbIAvMgDaJGnXoByDABsV4jcY7JeGEwHcVKs8ZG2DtBsbkuwTDZ2fMjGZhBKABbQ7gC6ANxkZDAyIAhgwCogzBBgAMryimAAFJJm-KzstqA4EAAejCAyhHLQtgD6ZnBCjN0AngCU5FSS0ipyAFaMAApSGXBmADzoWLgEEIQAfNqk3FShhhDGjGV7YiNS1BCOAIJQUIwr2PhEurE7TIVKEKrqTAB0hDgAAdiqUFtUBlpNsN9shgDBijV6totDpgEM9nCoLkZFBsrC4XD-iSylwiUSSf9xhMsfsRMg6cgGRAzEwUITsbj8cgyokiedKCIBnsEFkmK4IP8LBhiiBrncoANEmIyOz8l8SsZ5Y4AHLeIIABlsqVqMFAuGVQA

Comment: @Lesiak this is it. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in comments:

- the code you posted does not show how you created object with unmodifiable property
- you can create a new object and not use Object.assign to get rid of the error
- use `map` function in more idiomatic way

```
interface TaggedItem {
    name: string,
    tag: string
}
var subcategories = [{name:'gloves', tag:'wool'}, {name:'boots', tag: 'leather'}];

function setSubcat(val: string, index: number, _lang: any){
   var obj: Partial<TaggedItem> = {
      'name': val
   }
   var newArr: TaggedItem[] = subcategories.map((val, i)=>{
      if(index === i){
        return {
            ...val,
            ...obj
        } 
      } else {
        return {...val};
        // or return val; if you don't need a full copy
      }
   })
   console.log(newArr);
}

setSubcat('newName', 0, undefined);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwOYYgEwJKQC2yA3gFDKXIhyEQBcyAzmFKBgDQVViaMtsQGMgF8yANzhRmAVwBGCOJAwB7NhCbIAvMgDaJGnXoByDABsV4jcY7JeGEwHcVKs8ZG2DtBsbkuwTDZ2fMjGZhBKABbQ7gC6ANxkZDAyIAhgwCogzBBgAMryimAAFJJm-KzstqA4EAAejCAyhHLQtgD6ZnBCjN0AngCU5FSS0ipyAFaMAApSGXBmADzoWLgEEIQAfNqk3FShhhDGjGV7YiNS1BCOAIJQUIwr2PhEurE7TIVKEKrqTAB0hDgAAdiqUFtUBlpNsN9shgDBijV6totDpgEM9nCoLkZFBsrC4XD-iSylwiUSSf9xhMsfsRMg6cgGRAzEwUITsbj8aQqWURIkKcgAPTC5BqZA4sB47JleLwmDIPoqGTIHBZYxgK64ZBwZApMxmZAIFTAvpM86UEQDPYmkBMVwQf4WDDFEDXO5QAaJMRkdn5L4lYzuxwAOW8QQADLZUrUYKBcN6gA)

Comment: Yeah the way I was using map didn't help. This is really neat, thanks again.